# How can I add shadow on UIView, if there is another UIView bellow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Situation is follow: I Have this hierarchy of my Controller:

```
UIViewController:
 -UIView
   - UICollectionView
   - UITableView
```

My code:

```
 self.collectionView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    self.collectionView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
    self.collectionView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.collectionView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    self.collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    self.collectionView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.collectionView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

I need to add  shadow on the bottom of UICollectionView. If there is no UITableView, or it is hidden, I see shadow , but if there is UITableView - no shadow.

TableView is hidden: [image: http://joxi.ru/KAxgExsMY35E28?d=1]

TableView isn't hidden: [image: http://joxi.ru/823gQ6sJMZ0G2O?d=1]

So how can I display shadow?

Comment: Make your collection view as topview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your View hierarchy, exchange `collectionView` and `tableView` with each other only. It will definitely work and solve your problem.

**UIViewController**:

- UIView

  - UITableView
  - UICollectionView

For better help, share here, snapshot of your view hierarcy.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. I forgot about that. 
Thank you)